# hand gesture recognition in Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gesture, gesture-recognition

I am doing hand gesture recognition using ROS, OpenCV and Kinect depth image. I had read the following [paper](http://eeeweba.ntu.edu.sg/computervision/people/home/renzhou/Ren_Yuan_Zhang_MM11short.pdf) which stores the distance of the biggest contours from the center of the hand in one column and the angle (ranges from 0 to 359) between the contour point, center point and a fixed point in another column of the `biggest_contour.size() x 2` matrix. I have then plotted the matrix with x axis being the angle from 0 to 360 degrees and y axis being distance from the center of palm as follows:

The first palm image[image: https://sites.google.com/site/tushardobhal/images/45.jpg] and its corresponding plot: [image: https://sites.google.com/site/tushardobhal/images/rec1.jpg]

The second palm image [image: (sites.google.com/site/tushardobhal/images/122.jpg?attredirects=0)] and its corresponding plot:       [image: plot_\m/ (sites.google.com/site/tushardobhal/images/rec5.jpg?attredirects=0)]

I want to compare gestures in real time to these in the database. Since I could not understand Finger Earth Movers Distance method shown in the paper, I tried to do OpenCV template matching which succeeded in giving good results unless the two gestures were not close (like the shown \m/ and two finger pose). 
Can anyone tell me a good algorithm to compare two orientation vs distance matrices created above. Is it like Histogram Matching?? Although I have tried OpenCV's EMD method too but it did not give good result.

Here is my OpenCV version of the code which detects gestures in static images. However, I am doing gesture recognition in real time. I use just the OpenCV version of code to check if my algorithm is working with static images first.

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class histogram1D {

public:

Mat getCon(Mat m)
{
   vector<vector<Point> > cont;
   double area, max = 0;
   int x =0;
   findContours(m,cont,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
   for(int i=0;i<cont.size();i++)
   {
        area = contourArea(cont[i]);
        if(area>max)
            {
                max = area;
                x=i;
            }
   }
   Mat c(m.size(), m.type(), Scalar(0));
   drawContours(c, cont, x, Scalar(255), 1);
   Rect rect = boundingRect(cont[x]);
   Point cen(rect.x+rect.width/2, rect.y+(0.75*rect.height));

   float rad = sqrt(pow(rect.width/2, 2) + pow(rect.height/2, 2));

   Mat sig(cont[x].size(), 2, CV_32F, Scalar(0));
   for(int i = 0; i < cont[x].size(); i++)
   {
       float dis = norm(cont[x][i] - cen)/(rad);
      //if(dis <= 1.0)
         // dis = 0;
        sig.at<float>(i,0) = dis;
        double a1 = atan2(cont[x][i].y - cen.y, cont[x][i].x - cen.x);
        double a2 = atan2(rect.y + rect.height - cen.y, rect.x - cen.x);
        double a = a1 - a2;
        if(a<0) a = (2*CV_PI) + a;
        if(a > 2*CV_PI) a = a - 2*CV_PI;
        sig.at<float>(i,1) = a/(2*CV_PI);
   }
   //Sorting it according to increasing order of angles
   for(int i = 0; i < sig.rows; i++)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < sig.rows-1; j++)
      {
          if(sig.at<float>(j,1) > sig.at<float>(j+1,1))
          {
              float temp = sig.at<float>(j,0);
              sig.at<float>(j,0) = sig.at<float>(j+1,0);
              sig.at<float>(j+1,0) = temp;

              float tem = sig.at<float>(j,1);
              sig.at<float>(j,1) = sig.at<float>(j+1,1);
              sig.at<float>(j+1,1) = tem;
          }
      }
  }
  return sig;
}


Mat getRec(Mat hi)
{
     Mat rec(hi.rows, 360, CV_8U, Scalar(0));
     for(int i =0; i<hi.rows;i++)
     {
         line(rec,Point(hi.at<float>(i,1)*360, 0),Point(hi.at<float>(i,1)*360,hi.at<float>(i,0)*hi.rows*0.5),Scalar::all(255));

     }
     flip(rec,rec,0);
     return rec;
}


double getDist(Mat sig1, Mat sig2)
{
   double d;
   int size1, size2, f=0;
   if(sig1.rows<sig2.rows)
     { size1 = sig1.rows; size2 = sig2.rows;f = 0;}
   else
     {  size1 = sig2.rows; size2 = sig1.rows; f= 1;}

   /*for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
   {
      d += fabs((sig1.at<float>(i,0)) - (sig2.at<float>(i,0)));
   }
   for(int i = size1; i < size2; i++)
   {
      if(f==0) 
         d += (sig2.at<float>(i,0));
      if(f==1) 
         d += (sig1.at<float>(i,0));
   }

    return d;*/
    Mat res;
    if(f==0)
    {
       int r = sig2.rows - sig1.rows + 1;
       int c = 1;
       res.create(c, r, CV_32FC1);
       matchTemplate(sig2, sig1, res, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
    }
    else
    {
          int r = sig1.rows - sig2.rows + 1;
          int c = 1;
          res.create(r, c, CV_32FC1);
          matchTemplate(sig1, sig2, res, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
     }

     minMaxLoc(res, NULL, &d, NULL, NULL, Mat()); 

     return d;

 }
};

int main()
{
    Mat im1 =  imread("131.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat im2 = imread("145.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat im3 = imread("122.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat im5 = imread("82.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);


    if (im1.empty()) 
    {
        cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
    waitKey();
        return -1;
    }


 histogram1D h;
     resize( im1, im1, Size(80,120));
     resize( im2, im2, Size(80,120));
     resize( im3, im3, Size(80,120));
     resize( im5, im5, Size(80,120));


     blur( im1, im1, Size(3,3) );
     blur( im2, im2, Size(3,3) );
     blur( im3, im3, Size(3,3) );
     blur( im5, im5, Size(3,3) );


     Mat hi1 = h.getCon(im1);
     Mat rec1 = h.getRec(hi1);
     //FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
     //fs << "hi" << hi;


    Mat hi2 = h.getCon(im2);
    Mat rec2 = h.getRec(hi2);

    Mat hi3 = h.getCon(im3);
    Mat rec3 = h.getRec(hi3);

    Mat hi5 = h.getCon(im5);
    Mat rec5 = h.getRec(hi5);




    /*float ch =  EMD(hi1, hi1,  CV_DIST_L1);
    float ch1 = EMD(hi1, hi2, CV_DIST_L1);
    float ch2 = EMD(hi1, hi3, CV_DIST_L1);
    float ch3 = EMD(hi1, hi5, CV_DIST_L1);*/

   float ch =  h.getDist(hi1, hi1);
   float ch1 = h.getDist(hi1, hi2);
   float ch2 = h.getDist(hi1, hi3);
   float ch3 = h.getDist(hi1, hi5);

    /*double ch =  comparehist(hi1, hi1, CV_COMP_CsigQR);   
    double ch1 = comparehist(hi1, hi2, CV_COMP_CsigQR);
    double ch2 = comparehist(hi1, hi3, CV_COMP_CsigQR);
    double ch3 = comparehist(hi1, hi5, CV_COMP_CsigQR);*/

    // imshow("rec1.jpg", rec1); imshow("rec2.jpg", rec2); imshow("rec3.jpg", rec3); imshow("rec5.jpg", rec5);   
      cout<<ch<<" "<<ch1<<" "<<ch2<<" "<<ch3<<endl;



     waitKey();
 return(0);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? It sounds like your method works well.

Comment: Thanks for editing. No it does not work well. It works if I use completely different gestures but fails when similar looking gestures are compared especially in real time.

Comment: So I want to know a good algorithm to compare the orientation histogram type matrix like FEMD given in the paper I mentioned which I could not understand

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand the thing is that EMD allows for partial matching which is why you aren´t being able to identify 2 similar gestures (your 2º gesture is being matched as a subset of the first (the index and little fingers have distance 0 between the 2 images) , as for how to implement FEMD I'm trying to do that too.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar approach explained in this [paper](https://hal-imt.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/816596/filename/HCI_I_2011_final_v9.pdf):

From the first image, you create a contour, and save them as templates, then you compute the difference between each point of the contour with the point of the template.
You add error/template then you select the template with the smallest error (or nothing)

it's an application of $1 gesture recognizer but used otherwise, if you search youtube you'll find a video of it working.